# half cylinder parametrization

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Let S be the half cylinder $x^2+z^2=a^2$, where $z\le 0$ and $0\le y\le h$.

Compute the scalar function integral double integral $yz \ dS$.

I worked it out and I got

$-a^2h^2$  as my answer could anybody let me know if I got the right answer. Thanks!

Also are the signs as follows? $x$ is positive and $y$ negative and $z$ negative

Answer (score 0):

$-a^2h^2$ shows negative volume of 4 dimension. The correct integral is $\dfrac 1{2}\displaystyle\int_0^h\int _{-a}^{a}zdxdy=\frac{\pi a^2h}{2}$